# Textbox Event Handling

Tags: c#, winforms, events, listview, textbox

I have a form that has textboxes that display various code values. If I click within one of the textboxes that displays a code, how do i show the description value from the listview subitem into an adjacent textbox? The user clicks on a button to select a list of codes from a Listview that displays both the code and description values from the database.

I need to be able to display the appropriate description per code (there are 200 codes)

To be more specific:

If I click on textbox1(code1 value),  the appropriate description1 should appear in the "Description Textbox".

If I clik  on textbox2 (code2 value), the appropriate description2 should appear in the
"Description Textbox".

Current Approach below that only works once.. and does not work when you for example:
click on textbox1, then textbox2, but change your mind and want to see the description for textbox20. Textbox1's description is still displayed.

Code implemented thus far:

```
private void txtbYTRDICD1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    txtbICDDiagDesc.Text = _theICD9DCode.Description;
}
```

I'm working with C#.NET, in Visual Studio 2005. thanks tons

Answer (score 2):

Wow, there are a lot of Red Flags here.  Why on Earth would you name something "bYRTDICD1"?  Why would you put a description in a TextBox?  Do you want the user to edit the description?  Why would you use the MouseDown event?  Can't the user use the keyboard?

Random advice:

1. Use the Enter event, not MouseDown
2. Put a description in a label, not a text box
3. Use the TextBox.Tag property to store the description
4. Use a ComboBox to let the user select stuff instead of a list view
5. Design your UI so that descriptions are unnecessary

Comment: Why on Earth would you name something "bYRTDICD1"? :))) 100%; -Use the Enter event - on even MouseHover! and in general I can recommend tooltips for the description from tag.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, also 1.The textbox name is a user requirement.It's the name of the database field. I initially attempted to the use a LABEL instead,(ideal) because the users don't need to edit the description. However, i had trouble with the coding, which i why we are communicating :)Your alternative suggestions are valuable, however, the form was designed based upon the old apps design. So the listview stays LOL. Thanks again

Comment: about the Enter Event- i tried using it first because it seemed more applicable, but again.. referring to my previous explanation..the syntax i used just didn't work to store the description in the textbox.Have a goood one and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just a ToolTip control in order to dispatch descriptions on your textboxes.

```
myToolTip.SetToolTip(txtbYTRDICD1, _theICD9DCode.Description);
```